# Last object in a vector disappearing after applying erase() for the first time

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a very weird problem and I apologize in advance if what I am about to say sounds silly.

I am developing a simple 3D game, and I am using c++, OpenGL 4.1, and Xcode 9.2 on MacBook Pro. I am a beginner, and I am struggling with vectors of objects. In particular, I managed to create several instances of a given object and display all of them in my scene. I am now trying to handle the deletion of one object at a time, say the first for simplicity. Therefore, I simply apply the erase() function to the vector, but, even though only the first element in the vector is actually erased, the last one also disappears from the scene.
I checked that the iterator was scanning the updated list correctly (although there was no need since the deletion is outside the for loop). I also paused the program and looked into the memory to see if the last object was still present, and it was. I thought the last object was simply overlapping another one, but was not because its model transformation matrix was different from the others.
As a last test (I am desperate now), I have written a portion of code that re-push_back()s all the elements when none is left after repeatedly use erase(). The problem persists.
What could I be doing wrong?
Here is part of the code (imagine that the vector "blocks" has already 6 elements in the beginning):

```
if (fire){ // mouse button pressed
    fire = false;
    num_of_blocks--;
    blocks.erase(blocks.begin()); //delete first element, but last disappears!!
    if (num_of_blocks==0){
        first = true;
        num_of_blocks = 6;
    }

}
if (first){
    first = false;
    Vector3f pos = Vector3f(0,1,-3);
    for (int i=0; i<num_of_blocks;i++){
        pos.z() -= 2;
        Parallelepiped newBlock = Parallelepiped(_textureWall.GetID(),2.0f,0.5f,1.2f);
        blocks.push_back(newBlock);
        blocks[i].setPosition(pos);
    }
}
    for (vector<Parallelepiped>::iterator it = blocks.begin(); it !=blocks.end(); it++){
    drawObject(&shaders[0], &(*it));
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's this `num_of_blocks` business about? Why do you need that variable?

Comment: Are you keeping track of any iterators elsewhere in your program?  `erase` will invalidate any iterators to objects after the one that got removed.

Comment: @mnistic num_of_blocks counts how many blocks are left because every time I push the mouse button one is deleted. I may not need it, but I will remove it afterwards.

Comment: @StephenNewell The one you see is the only place where I use the iterator. The vector is updated always before the iterator is initialized.

Comment: I can share the entire code with you, if you want. I don't mind.

Comment: I tried almost everything. It seems that somehow I have a synchronization problem. Every time I change the number of elements in the array, the GPU is not updated as fast as the RAM. Could this be the cause? I see too random phenomena.

Comment: Yes please provide all code.

Comment: @mnistic I have an update. Whatever I  dynamically do with object, add or delete, I have unexpected behaviors. For instance, if I add the same bricks 5 times by pushing a mouse button, the 4th changes shape. If I then add a few extra block, the 4th gets back to what it was supposed to be. I am now defining my object once, and each instance has a vector of states. Then I scan the vector, extract the model transform matrix and draw accordingly. So, I don't have the old code. I could easily remake it, but how can I share it (it's huge)?

Comment: I have made a video showing the visual error I got, in case my explanation wasn't clear.

Comment: It may be best to post a new question then, you'll get more attention that way anyway.